# Why is a type alias not allowed to be a friend class name in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, friend, type-alias

```
class A {    
};

class B {
    using C = A;

    // Compilation error: 
    // Type alias 'C' cannot be referenced with a class specifier 
    friend class C;    
};
```

**Why is a type alias not allowed to be a friend class name in C++?**

**What's the rationale behind?**

Comment: The program [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/sczvGKvjj) with msvc.

Comment: You're wrong in assuming that a type alias is not allowed to be a friend. The correct syntax for befriending type alias `C` is `friend C` instead of `friend class C;`.

Comment: When you wrote `friend class C;` you're making a global class named `C` a friend of `B`. You just need to remove the `class` kewyord to make the alias a friend.

Comment: The error tells you that the type alias `C` can't be specified with a `class` specifier, so just remove the `class` specifier and make it `friend C;`.

Comment: not a bug. msvc got non-standard behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is a type alias not allowed to be a friend class name in C++?

You're wrong in assuming that a type alias is not allowed to be in a friend declaration. The correct syntax for befriending through alias `C` is `friend C;` instead of `friend class C;`.

---

Note also that the program is **ill-formed** and msvc is wrong in [not giving a diagnostic](https://godbolt.org/z/jzK19jY9W). This can be seen from [dcl.type.elab](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#5.sentence-3):

> If the identifier or simple-template-id resolves to a class-name or enum-name, the elaborated-type-specifier introduces it into the declaration the same way a simple-type-specifier introduces its type-name ([dcl.type.simple]).
> **If the identifier** or simple-template-id **resolves to a typedef-name** ([dcl.typedef], [temp.names]), **the elaborated-type-specifier is ill-formed.**

(emphasis mine)

And since the identifier `C` does resolve to a *typedef-name* the elaborated-type-specifier(`class C`) and hence the program is **ill-formed**.